# MVC 5 Razor view not rendering HTML within if condition

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

This is the MVC 5 razor view code:  ForestView.cshtml

```
@model Forest.Tree
@{
   var resultHtml = string.Empty;
 }
<div id="divTreeSearch>
@(Html.Kendo().PanelBar().
                         Name("panelbar")
                         .Items(panelbar =>
                                        {panelbar.Add()                                                   
                               .Content(@<text>@Html.Partial("_TreeSearch", Model, ViewData)</text>);}))
</div>
<div id="divTreeSearchResult">
@if(Model.TreeResultObj != null)
{
  resultHtml = Html.ContentFromPartial("_TreeReport", Model.TreeResultObj);

  @Html.Raw(resultHtml);    -- Not working
  @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(resultHtml)); -- Not Working
  Html.Raw(resultHtml);    -- Not working
  Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(resultHtml)); -- Not Working

  Model.resultStringSaved  = resultHtml;
  @Html.DisplayText("resultStringSaved"); -- Not Working

   @Html.Raw("<text>Test</text>") -- Even this is not working

}

 @Html.Raw(Model.resultStringSaved) -- Not Working
 @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.resultStringSaved)) -- Not Working
 @Html.DisplayText("resultStringSaved") -- Not Working

  @Html.Raw("<text>Test</text>") -- This is Working
</div>
```

ForestView.cshtml - @model Forest.Tree
_TreeSearch.cshtml - @model Forest.Tree
_TreeReport.cshtml - @model Forest.SearchData.Results

The projerty TreeResultObj in the model `Forest.Tree` is of type `Forest.SearchData.Results`

The `ForestView.cshtml` is the main view which loads initially and displays the search inputs from the `_TreeSearch` partial
When search criteria entered and a 'search' button is clicked (all this is from the `_TreeSearch`) - a ajax call is make and the `TreeSearch(id tree)` action is called

The action again returns the main 'ForestView' - however now the model property 'TreeResultObj' is populated. so the code within the 'if conditon' in the 'ForestView' executed and calls another partial to get the content back as HTML string, which is saved in the 'resultHtml' variable

At this point I can see the Html Sting like `"<Text>blah blah blah</text>"` 
However trying to display the HTML string below the search panel in the main 'ForestView' is not working - I have tried almost every possible way.

Any text within the if condition is not rendered - it is an ajax call so there is no page refresh - I can see the HTML string value and also save it as a Model property but cannot get to display it in the main view.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dobbins they have clearly already tried that in the question

Comment: I means that `TreeResultObj` is `null`

Comment: TreeResultObj is not null, also I am getting the HTML string back from loadcontentsfromparital

Comment: Trying what Marc Gravell suggested

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in the View, and tried to see the value for TreeResultObj?

Comment: [Can you provide an mcve?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: yes when I put a break point - i see TreeResultObj has value and so does 'resultHTML' - I cannot even get a simple text in the if block to be rendered..

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem trying to generate links (`<a>` elements) and Html.Raw doesn't render the links properly. Did you find a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

At that point, you are just invoking a method and ignoring the result. Try:

```
@: @Html.Raw(resultHtml)
```

The `@:` switches to output mode. Note: if you had used something that was clearly markup, it would have switched automatically. For example:

```
<div>@Html.Raw(resultHtml)</div>
```

Comment: It is not working Marc... the HTML string is good - however when I view page source I can see the div 'divTreeSearchResult' but it is empty... the HTML string has <Script> section and javascript functions in it... could that be the reason ?

Comment: I even cannot display something like :      @: @Html.Raw("<strong>ResultTest</strong>")

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue but I could make it to working. I wanted to open a div start and conditionally end it within a for loop.

Put any dummy HTML element before the @Html.Raw

```
<div id="divTreeSearchResult">
@if(Model.TreeResultObj != null)
 {
  resultHtml = Html.ContentFromPartial("_TreeReport", Model.TreeResultObj);
  <span>dummySpan</span>
  @Html.Raw(resultHtml);    
  @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(resultHtml)); 
  @Html.Raw(resultHtml);   
  @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(resultHtml)); 

 Model.resultStringSaved  = resultHtml;
 @Html.DisplayText("resultStringSaved"); 

 @Html.Raw("<text>Test</text>") 

}

@Html.Raw(Model.resultStringSaved) 
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.resultStringSaved)) 
@Html.DisplayText("resultStringSaved") 

@Html.Raw("<text>Test</text>") 
</div>
```

After you place a dummy html element there all the below @Html.Raw will work

Happy Coding

Tarak

Answer (score -1):

1 - And the content from render should be violating HTML syntax and Razor normally doesn't render wrong HTML content.
2 - Enclose the HTML.Raw(resultHtml) into dev.

Comment: It is already enclosed within <div> tags. Also I checked the source html, it seems good.... the <div id="divTreeSearchResult"> </div> is there, but it is empty. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

After zillions of tests in a full-day:
Change use of:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mensagem))
```

by:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.DisplayTextFor(modelItem => item.Mensagem))
```

You will get the rendered HTML withou any <>!!!