# MVC Razor not rendering HTML correctly inside a @foreach loop

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to display text when you hover over table data and trying to format it using HTML. I have the text stored in the title. I'm able to get the data to display fine when I hover over it, but for the life of me, I cannot get the HTML to render correctly. So for an example, if I wanted to make the **text bold** in the title, it would look like this `<b>text bold</b>` when I hover over the title. The fix seems like it should be simple, but I cannot figure this out. I did find a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41251838/mvc-5-razor-view-not-rendering-html-within-if-condition) of user having the same issue, but there was no real solid solution.

How can I get HTML to render within a `@foreach` loop properly?

```
<td data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-original-title="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Report_Name)" data-content="@foreach (var t in item.report_change_log_list) {  @Html.Raw("<div style='text-align: left'><b>" + t.effective_date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "</b> : " + t.change.ToString() + "</br></br>" + "</div>")  }">
                                            @if (item.report_change_log_list.Any())
                                            {
                                                @Html.Raw("<i class='fa fa-stack-exchange fa-2x' style='color: #205686' aria-hidden='true'></i>");
                                            }
                                        </td>
```

Comment: So any html that I plug in would show up as text. I was using <b> as a very basic example. So if I added <div><strong></strong></div> all that would show as plain text.

Comment: Why are you using `.Raw()` at all, it makes no sense.

Comment: What would you suggest?

Comment: [Don't use raw, there is no need](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gtf66w)

Comment: Thanks Erik. I see what you are talking about now. I think the reason why I used Html.Raw was because i'm including values from the item list. Can I still avoid using the Html.Raw if it actually looks like this? Html.Raw("<div style='text-align: left'><b>" + t.effective_date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "</b> : " + t.change.ToString() + "</br></br>" + "</div>"). I'm trying to re-create what you have in my code. But this is a big help. I'm learning a lot today. Thank you.

Comment: [Sure, Razor is pretty powerful](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NhoReR).

Comment: Recommended Reading: [ASP.NET MVC 3: Razor’s @: and <text> syntax](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax)

Comment: That seem to work. Thank you very much for helping me do this the correct way. Taking a look at that article. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add `data-html="true"` to your `td` tag as follows:

```
<td data-html="true" data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-original-title="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Report_Name)" data-content="@foreach (var t in item.report_change_log_list) {  @Html.Raw("<b>Bold Doesn't work</b>")  }">
    @if (item.report_change_log_list.Any())
    {
        @Html.Raw("<i class='fa fa-stack-exchange fa-2x' style='color: #205686' aria-hidden='true'></i>");
    }
</td>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qy9Az/2760/) is a fiddle which illustrates this